# How to make material-ui fields render correctly after calling reset for react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

I'm trying to make a page for editing but the problem is react MUI does not properly render text fields after I updated my form data via `reset` method of react-hook-form.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

However, if I click submit, react-hook-form calls my function with proper data, but the form itself presented incorrectly.

I made an example to reproduce it.
Here is my code (you can also playround with it in [https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-bush-dy8qh8](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-bush-dy8qh8?file=/src/model.ts)):

model:

```
import * as yup from "yup";
import { InferType } from "yup";

export const SCHEMA = yup.object({
  string: yup.string().defined().required("Required").max(100, "Too long"),
  number: yup.number().defined().required("Required").min(1, "Must be positive")
});

export type FormValues = InferType<typeof SCHEMA>;

export const INITIAL_VALUES: FormValues = {
  string: "",
  number: 0
};
```

And the form:

```
import { Grid, Box, TextField, Typography, Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { SCHEMA, INITIAL_VALUES, FormValues } from "./model";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function EditItemView() {
  const resolver = yupResolver(SCHEMA);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm<FormValues>({ resolver, mode: "all" });

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    // pretend loading from server
    setTimeout(() => {
      reset({ number: 944, string: "a new string" });
      setLoading(false);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box padding={2}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((formData) => console.log(formData))}>
        <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="stretch" spacing={2}>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h5">Edit item</Typography>
            {isLoading && <Typography>Loading...</Typography>}
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <TextField
              {...register("string")}
              variant="standard"
              fullWidth
              label="Type a string"
              defaultValue={INITIAL_VALUES.string}
              error={!!errors["string"]}
              helperText={errors["string"]?.message}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <TextField
              {...register("number")}
              variant="standard"
              fullWidth
              label="Type a positive number"
              defaultValue={INITIAL_VALUES.string}
              error={!!errors["number"]}
              helperText={errors["number"]?.message}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item container justifyContent="flex-end">
            <Grid>
              <Button disabled={isLoading} type="submit" variant="contained">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </form>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found a simple way to fix it. I need to use `InputLabelProps: { shrink }` and manully tell it wheter to shrink the label or not depending on value:

```
import { Grid, Box, TextField, Typography, Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { SCHEMA, INITIAL_VALUES, FormValues } from "./model";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function EditItemView() {
  const resolver = yupResolver(SCHEMA);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    getValues,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm<FormValues>({ resolver, mode: "all" });

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    // pretend loading from server
    setTimeout(() => {
      reset({ number: 944, string: "a new string" });
      setLoading(false);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box padding={2}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((formData) => console.log(formData))}>
        <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="stretch" spacing={2}>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h5">Edit item</Typography>
            {isLoading && <Typography>Loading...</Typography>}
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <TextField
              {...register("string")}
              variant="standard"
              fullWidth
              label="Type a string"

              InputLabelProps={{ shrink: !!getValues("string") }}

              defaultValue={INITIAL_VALUES.string}
              error={!!errors["string"]}
              helperText={errors["string"]?.message}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <TextField
              {...register("number")}
              variant="standard"
              fullWidth
              label="Type a positive number"
              defaultValue={INITIAL_VALUES.number}

              InputLabelProps={{ shrink: !!getValues("number") }}

              error={!!errors["number"]}
              helperText={errors["number"]?.message}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item container justifyContent="flex-end">
            <Grid>
              <Button disabled={isLoading} type="submit" variant="contained">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </form>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `styled` version of the `TextField` component to make it act like `OutlinedInput` like this -

```ts
import {TextField as MuiTextField, styled, TextFieldProps} from "@mui/material";

const TextField = styled(MuiTextField, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "notched"
})<TextFieldProps & { notched?: boolean }>(({ notched, theme }) =>
  notched
    ? {
        "& > label": {
          marginTop: -theme.spacing(3),
          transform: "scale(0.75)"
        }
      }
    : {}
);
```

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ride-9yp49f?file=/src/EditItemView.tsx) with your example.

Comment: I tried, but `notched` is not a part of TextField's API: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/ therefore causing a compile-time error. And the second one just does not work.

Comment: Oh, pardon me, `notched` is InputProps sub-property. But unfortunately it does not work either

Comment: It used to work, maybe it changed, anyways, you can create a customized version of it that takes a `notched` prop and gives you the result of `OutlinedInput`'s `notched` prop. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I actually found more simple way (without custom component) and posted the answer.